# How to go about computing the maximum roundoff error?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Considering the Taylor series with remainder,

[Taylor Series with remainder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yyGW.png)

It is known that the function evaluations f(x+h) and f(x-h) in floating arithmetic are not exact.

Assuming that [Floating Point evaluations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6pU2.png) are the respective floating point evaluations of f(x+h) and f(x-h), where ϵ< ϵ_MACH.

How to go about computing the maximum roundoff error?

I have tried working this out and I have been coming to the conclusion that the maximum error is ϵ_MACH. However, I doubt that this is correct.

Would anyone mind showing me how to work this out?

Comment: The maximum roundoff error of what quantity?

Comment: @CarlChristian I do not know how to explain this briefly but I hope that attaching a screenshot of the question would help. Link: https://ibb.co/Hp5Btvj

Comment: We *all* have to write questions and answers which are searchable. Images are not searchable and third party images vanish all the time. Take the time you need to write out your question clearly as well as your current approach.

Comment: This, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497660/central-difference, could be a similar question. Also relevant could be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600018/why-do-we-need-numerical-method-of-differentiation, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488262/how-to-approximate-relative-error, or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019573/4th-order-accurate-difference-formula-less-accurate